# Has the SoundCloud API changed how to write the release property on the tracks endpoint?

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

I've been using [mptre’s PHP](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) SoundCloud wrapper for years. Recently the API functionality changed. The `release` property in the `tracks` endpoint ([as outlined here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)) stopped writing. This is true for both PHP and the official js sdk.

```
    $client = new Services_Soundcloud($sc_clientid, $sc_clientsecret);
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $client->put('tracks/' . $trackID, array(
        'track[title]' => 'New Title', // this works
        'track[release]' => '0001' // this doesn't work,
    ));
```

Has anyone else noticed this change? Or is there another way to write to the `release` property?

---

#### Update 1:

`release` property works fine on *playlists*. Still broken on *tracks*.

#### Update 2:

Same results for the official javascript SDK (v 3.3.2)

#### Testing of all RW properties on August 2, 2020:

- **title:** ✅
- **permalink:** ✅
- **release:** ❌
- **sharing:** ❌
- **embeddable_by:** ❌
- **purchase_url:** ❌
- **purchase_title:** ✅
- **description:** ✅
- **genre:** ✅
- **tag_list:** ✅
- **label_id:** ❌
- **label_name:** ❌
- **streamable:** ❌
- **license:** ✅
- **commentable:** ✅
- **isrc:** ❌

Comment: Hi. There was a change to make this field read-only. I'm interested in learning about your use case to tag a new track with a release title from the API. Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: @RahulRumalla We use the release property for unique track codes. Which is very useful in production music libraries. See screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/o0u8rGgo